Foreign animated movie about a princess married off to a powerful wizard
I remember that she's kept in a tower until she can be married, and that she sneaks into town to see people sew or something. Anyway, one day several princes bring great gifts from all over the world, and she finds out one of the prince's battles with the natives to get this orb thing as a gift, and she calls him a thief for stealing their relic from them. The king is then convinced by a wizard that she is lying because she is infected with an evil spirit of some sort, and promises to cleanse her in return for her hand in marriage or something. He then magics her into looking like a woman and then spirits her away.
He then locks her up in a dungeon, but she has a wishing ring with three wishes or something. She's magic-ed not to want to escape, so she wastes the first two wishes on stupid things like cloth or a bed or something... and then she escapes I think... and tricks the wizard... at some point... and finds a rock that creates water... and there was something to do with people being turned into frogs i think...
Anyway, this all takes place in a sort of post apocalyptic type world, hundreds of years after a great magical civilization crumbled.
If anyone has a clue, I'd love to hear it. I've been trying to find this movie again for ages.

Foreign to whom?

You're looking for Princess Arete from 2001:

Confined in the castle tower by her father, Princess Arete spends her days watching the world outside her window. Sometimes she seeks out to watch the common people at work.

The rest fits too; you remembered every detail quite well. Your question is pretty much the Wiki plot synopsis sans the names. ;) (The wizard who can control water is Boax.) Here's the trailer:



